# How do I make my Search Field show some text and make it disappear when it's clicked

Tags: html, forms

I want my search field to say "Where are you" make it disappear when clicked and and appear again when if he clicks outside leaving it blank.

This is the search form:

```
<div id="search-10" class="widget_search">
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://chusmix.com/?s=" onsubmit="window.location = action + s.value + '+: <?php the_search_query() ?>'; return false;">
 <div>
 <input class="ubicacion" type="text" value="" name="s" id="s2" style="margin-left:0px;">
 <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Buscar">
 </div>
 </form></div>
```

I tried this but for some reason it didn't work:

```
<li id="search-10" class="widget_search">
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://chusmix.com/">
    <div>
    <input class="ubicacion" type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" style="margin-left:418px;">
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Buscar" onblur=" if(this.value== '') this.value='Where are you';" onfocus=" if(this.value=='Where are you') this.value=''; " value="Where are you" name="keyword" />
    </div>
    </form></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fake the border of the input using a div, and position the real input and a label inside it - one of top of the other.

Conceal the label when the element gets the focus, put it back when the focus is lost if the value is blank.

There is an [example using jQuery](http://dorward.me.uk/tmp/label-work/example.html).

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to change it to use it on my code but I'm having some problems.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work when I put it on my page, not even when I copy paste it without changing anything.

Comment: If you copy/paste it without changing anything, then the path to jQuery will be wrong.

Comment: Sorry I should have pointed out I'm very new to web design. I don't even know what jQuery is

Comment: jQuery is a library. It contains a big pile of functions that make life more convenient for the JS programmer. See also YUI and Mootools (among others).

Comment: Thanks, so how do I find the path to jQuery or install jQuery or in other words what do I do to make it work?

Comment: I copied the minified version of jQuery to a file named jquery.js. I copied your code to my footer and changed the path to my .js file but jQuery isn't working. I just tried with the uncompressed version of jQuery and it didn't work either, do you know what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Based on that description, no.

Answer (score 1):

This removes the default text when a user clicks on the search form and adds it back when the user clicks off the search form.

```
<form id="searchform" method="get" action="search.php">
<input class="textbox" value="Search" name="s" id="s" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}" type="text">
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="" class="searchsubmit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

See the example below for raw javascript -

```
<input type="text" onblur=" if(this.value== '') this.value='Where are you';" onfocus=" if(this.value=='Where are you') this.value=''; " value="Where are you" name="keyword" />
```

Beside this, you can use jquery, dojo, mootools plugin to handle this.

Comment: Please don't abuse the value as a label. That isn't what it is for, and will never be readable for screenreaders (which focus elements before reading their content).

Comment: In the end it didn't work anyway, for some reason it stops working when I mix it with my search bar.

Comment: you might did a mistake, check carefully

Comment: I changed 5th line for this (I copied it above so it's more clear): '<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Buscar" onblur=" if(this.value== '') this.value='Where are you';" onfocus=" if(this.value=='Where are you') this.value=''; " value="Where are you" name="keyword" />'

Comment: you've put value="Buscar". Do you want Buscar as default value? if so - try as following - <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit"  onblur=" if(this.value== '') this.value='Buscar';" onfocus=" if(this.value=='Buscar') this.value=''; " value="Buscar" name="keyword" />

Comment: I didn't want it to say Buscar anyway I tried putting that and it just shows the search box blank. I'm trying it on the footer of my page www.chusmix.com would I be bothering too much if I asked you to take a look at it? It's driving me mad because all seems right but still it doesn't work

Comment: Just put this - <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" onblur=" if(this.value== '') this.value='Where are you';" onfocus=" if(this.value=='Where are you') this.value=''; " value="Where are you" name="keyword" />

Comment: It doesn't work. It should, I see no reason why it wouldn't. Thanks a lot for all the effort anyway

Comment: can i see the site where it implemented?